# NSAttributedStringKey.attachment versus NSAttachmentAttributeName

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, ios11

I'm having problems with NSAttributedStringKey.attachment versus NSAttachmentAttributeName. Here's the relevant code:

```
    var key: Any?
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        key = NSAttributedStringKey.attachment
    }
    else {
        key = NSAttachmentAttributeName
    }
```

One of two things are happening. In the actual place where I'm trying to use this code (a Cococapod of my own design, with a deployment target of iOS 8 and now building with Xcode 9), I get an error:

```
Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'attachment'
```

Or, if I just make a new example project and set the deployment target at iOS 8, I get:

```
'NSAttachmentAttributeName' has been renamed to 'NSAttributedStringKey.attachment'
```

This is not the behavior I'd expect with `#available`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `String` vs `struct` difference is between Swift 3 (uses `String`s such as `NSAttachmentAttributeName`) and Swift 4 (uses struct static attributes such as `NSAttributedStringKey.attachment`), not between iOS <11 and iOS >=11. For instance, you can use `NSAttributedStringKey.attachment` and similar in any supporting version of iOS (e.g. `.attachment` is available since iOS 7) within a Swift 4 project. `#available` doesn't apply because it's a Swift language version difference rather than an OS version difference.

Ensure your pod is set to the correct Swift version and it should then work as expected. You can tell CocoaPods that by adding a `.swift-version` file at the top of your project:

```
$ echo 4.0 >.swift-version
```

This magical version file is mentioned in passing in a CocoaPods blog post from last year: http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.1.0/

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew Herbert! It seems like I had to explicitly set the SWIFT_VERSION of the pod in the build settings, but perhaps doing a `pod update` was insufficient after changing the .swift-version. In any event, using Swift 4 definitely solves the problem.